# how we add or remove readonly attribute from textbox on clicking radion button in cakephp using jquery?

Tags: jquery, cakephp

Here is my cakephp generated HTML **radio box** and **text box** script:

```
<input type="radio" id="need_staff_on_site" name="data[CaterRequest][need_staff_on_site]" value="yes" class="staff_on_site"><span>Yes</span>

<input type="radio" id="need_staff_on_site" name="data[CaterRequest][need_staff_on_site]" class="staff_on_site" value="no"><span>No</span>

How many staff?<input type="text" maxlength="3" id="no_of_staff" name="data[CaterRequest][staff_needed]" class="txtboxSml2" readonly="readonly">
```

**jquery Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.staff_on_site').click(function(){
   $arr=$(this).val();
   if($arr == "yes"){ $("#no_of_staff").removeAttr("readonly"); }
   if($arr == "no"){ $("#no_of_staff").attr("readonly", "readonly"); }
  });
});
```

[**Demo jsfiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/J8DvX/16/)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In your Case you can write the following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.staff_on_site').click(function(){

     var rBtnVal = $(this).val();

     if(rBtnVal == "yes"){
         $("#no_of_staff").attr("readonly", false); 
     }
     else{ 
         $("#no_of_staff").attr("readonly", true); 
     }
   });
});
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P4QWx/3/

Answer (score 7):

You could use `prop` as well. Check the following code below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.staff_on_site').click(function(){

     var rBtnVal = $(this).val();

     if(rBtnVal == "yes"){
         $("#no_of_staff").prop("readonly", false); 
     }
     else{ 
         $("#no_of_staff").prop("readonly", true); 
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: Note that at least on select tags this won't work (Arun Jain solution does).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove attr like this

```
$('.editname').removeAttr('readonly');
```

You can add readonly attr like this

```
$('.editname').attr('readonly', true);
```