# How to remove readonly attribute when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I remove the `readonly` attribute when the `Edit` button is clicked? My codes is working if clicked but after one second the input form is back to `readyonly`.

```
<input class="form-control" name="fullname" value="<php echo $fullname; ?>" readonly/>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnEdit" > edit </button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnEdit').click(function(){
            $("input[name='fullname']").attr("readonly", false);   
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: button lead to a form submit?

Comment: I would think that you have some other code which make the field read only. You better to find what code is responsible for making the fields read only. Maybe the form gets updated with ajax request?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/ - `readonly` is a boolean attribute meaning its presence is all that is needed to work.

Comment: `removeAttr` is not the right method. Use [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead. Example `$(element).prop('readonly', false)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how we add or remove readonly attribute from textbox on clicking radion button in cakephp using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259031/how-we-add-or-remove-readonly-attribute-from-textbox-on-clicking-radion-button-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this  you have to use **removeAttr**  [reference link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_removeattr.asp)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('#btnEdit').click(function()
 {
   $("input[name='fullname']").removeAttr("readonly");  
 });

 });

 </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use [jQuery removeAttr](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnEdit').click(function(){
        $("input[name='fullname']").removeAttr( "readonly" ); 
    });
});
```

Comment: @expert123 no problem, could you please accept the answer if it works