# How to remove attribute "readonly" Using JQuery

Tags: css, html

I'm implementing any bulletin Free board pages applied Secret and non-secret by the board's page password number.

I want to implement if the checkbox that distinguish whether The writings are secret is checked, I want to remove  readonly attribute of the password for applying the secret bulletin.

The password's id = bbs_password

the checkbox id = secret_yn

because of all source are my privacy, I can't attach it on this directly. Please understand me.

alternately, I attach a part of sourced codes by photo.

This is what I have so far :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#bbs_password').attr('readonly','readonly')


if($('input:checkbox[id="secret_yn"]').is(":checked") == true){
    $('#bbs_password').removeAttr('readonly','readonly');
    if(document.bbs_write_form.bbs_password.value == ""){
        alert("input the password!); 
        document.bbs_write_form.bbs_password.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
thanks very very much for reading this.

Comment: Put on code, not an image

Comment: refer link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259031/how-we-add-or-remove-readonly-attribute-from-textbox-on-clicking-radion-button-i

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how we add or remove readonly attribute from textbox on clicking radion button in cakephp using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259031/how-we-add-or-remove-readonly-attribute-from-textbox-on-clicking-radion-button-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set element as read-only:

```
$('#bbs_password').prop('readonly', true);
```

And to switch it back to editable:

```
$('#bbs_password').prop('readonly', false);
```

If you have jQuery version older than 1.9, you need to use instead:

```
$('#bbs_password').attr('readonly', true);
```

Comment: Your 'older than 1.9' code is exactly the same as your other code. Do you mean 'attr'?

Answer (score 0):

Depend on your jQuery version try this:

```
$('.selector').prop('readonly', false);
Or
$('.selector').attr('readonly', false);
```